# Validation for every single radtab in Telerik RadTabStrip

Tags: c#, tabs, telerik

I have a tabstrip with 5 tabs 
I need validation group for every single TABs.
I want to acheive the below result

When i click on the second tab, only the FIRST tab needs to be validated
When i click on the third tab, only the SECOND tab needs to be validated and so on.

and  If i'm in second tab, and clicked the FIRST tab, i dont want to consider whether SECOND tab is validated or not, i just want to move to FIRST tab

In short, i want validation group to be active for few tabs and inactive for few tabs.

Help me out to achieve this guys

Answer (score 0):

This code is basically just pseudo-code since I'm not familiar with the Telerik Rad* API.

```
RadTab previous = FIRST_TAB;

void RadTab_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    // this will be tab #N
    var tab = (RadTab)sender;

    // disregard the first tab
    if (tab.Index == 0 || previous.Index > tab.Index) return;

    // validate N-1
    radTabStrip.Tabs[tab.Index - 1].Validate();
}

void RadTab_OnLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
     previous = (RadTab)sender;
}
```